# Ubuntu 18.04 not resolving dns queries to specific host

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

I'm on my desktop machine (xubuntu 18.04, upgraded from xubuntu 16.04) and I'm trying to resolve `www.cnmv.es` and I get no answer:

```
$ dig www.cnmv.es
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> www.cnmv.es
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 53370
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cnmv.es.           IN  A

;; Query time: 105 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 28 17:33:30 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

Any other query works fine, as far as I know. My dns servers are configured, through DCHP (also tried to configure it statically without results), to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

```
 $  sudo systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (wlp3s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4
```

But if I try to ask directly to the dns server 8.8.8.8 with the `@` parameter of dig i get results.

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.cnmv.es     

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.cnmv.es
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33002
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cnmv.es.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.cnmv.es.        0   IN  CNAME   internet.cnmv.es.
internet.cnmv.es.   9   IN  A   5.40.196.142
internet.cnmv.es.   0   IN  A   195.53.156.42
internet.cnmv.es.   0   IN  A   88.84.92.42
internet.cnmv.es.   0   IN  A   88.84.91.42

;; Query time: 107 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 28 17:43:50 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

I've tried to clean the dns cache, restart the machine, change the dns name servers and the problem persists.

Comment: Hi - please can you edit/paste the output of `nslookup www.cnmv.es` and maybe `sudo netstat -antup | grep LISTEN`

Comment: nslookup www.cnmv.es
Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find www.cnmv.es: SERVFAIL

Comment: sudo netstat -antup | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      838/systemd-resolve